# Перенос 3D модели из 3DMax в Unity

Tags: unity3d, 3dsmax

Необходимо перенести модель из 3DMax в Unity. В 3DMax создаю всё по размерам. Однако при переноси в Unity все размеры теряются, причём скалируются не в 10 кратном размере. Как понимаю в Unity такого понятия как размерность нету. Поэтому необходимо принимать единицу по координатам как метр. Как перенести модель правильно, что бы размеры полностью сохранились?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации написано про параметр [ScaleFactor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/HOWTO-importObject.html) в настройках импорта. Пользуйтесь, все отлично настраивается)